# Add DataSource to UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, datasource

in my C# WPF interface I designed several UserControls that today are updated NOT-AUTOMATICALLY when source (string array) is changed by user or programmatically by the system.

In order to semplify the code and speed-up the update I'm trying to add **Datasource** to my custom **UserControls** (e.g. the simplest one is a rectangle that change color if the source is 0 or 1) and bind the data.
I read about *ComplexBindingPropertiesAttribute Class* but I'm not so sure thisis the right way or not.

Do you have any suggestion about the possible use of **Datasource** I mentioned?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: It is unclear what a "DataSource" is supposed to be here. A UserControl would typically expose a set of bindable properties, i.e. dependency properties.

Comment: Dear Clemens, thanks for the reply, I'm checking right now how to use dependency properties, I'm not familiar with that, do you have a good example or tutorial to share? Thanks and best regards

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Why don't you bind to a view model that implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001077)?

Comment: This is another way I evaluated but I'm missing the connection between the string array and the view model. The esplanation/examples I found are usually relates to a simple value